# Font awesome icons not showing in Wordpress after site address URL change

Tags: wordpress, font-awesome

This may be an obvious question for those of you more advanced in coding than myself...but I created a website in WordPress but their domain is hosted elsewhere.  They changed the A name and it now points to the site, but the font awesome icons are now square boxes.  How can I fix this? Is there a simple way?

Many thanks for any help/guidance.

Alison

Comment: Make sure you include the correct path to your fonts file in the href

Answer (score 2):

Super late, but hopefully this saves someone a lot of time. After migrating an existing Wordpress site to a new domain, I too encountered icons missing (both on the front-end and the back-end administration). After a long search and applying different methods, I found the database still listed the original/old domain within the "option" table.

Using phpMyAdmin, select the "option" table. Within "option" you will see the "site" and "home" rows. If the value has the old domains, you will need to change it to match the sites URLs (Located on the Administration dashboard under Settings > WordPress Address (URL) & Site Address (URL). To change the value, click Edit > and update the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Fix the problem in less then 2 mins. Simple replacement of /font-awesome/5.13.0/css/fontawesome.min.css with /font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css and also font-awesome/5.13.0/js/fontawesome.min.js with /font-awesome/5.13.0/js/all.min.js can fix this issue. https://youtu.be/_GV_pEmLCLU

Answer (score 0):

I know this is 2 years old, but I just ran into a similar problem and the answer given by Owais did not feel right to me (getting CSS from another site).

This happened to me for the exact same reason as it did for OP. I migrated my website to another host and another domain-name. After doing that I ran a rename-script for the DB (thousants of hard-coded URLs were replaced).

However, as it turns out, my theme was also using hard-coded URLs in the CSS files and in some JS files, as they were generated (upload/fusion-scripts and upload/fusion-styles). After replacing the hardcoded URLs in these files (I used visual studio, but you can use any bulk-replace tool) everything worked fine again.

Comment: I know this is even later, but seeing "fusion" in there and thinking about the Avada theme which I just moved and which caused the same problem - THE ACTUAL SOLUTION IS: Just go to Theme Options and click save changes again (without making any really). This will reset the fusion css cache and all will be good.

Comment: I really love you @ChinaWhite

Comment: Ditto, you're a lifesaver, @ChinaWhite!

Answer (score 0):

Just another idea to throw in here - after transferring the site to the new server, and running this [handy script](https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB) to replace all references of the old url with the new one, I was still having the same issue with font awesome.  The solution was to go to Settings / General and set the Endurance Cache to Off (0).  Refreshed the site and all was well.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had that problem changing the url using the constants WP_HOME WP_SITEURL at wp-config.php

When I changed through the wp-admin using the RELOCATE flag, worked

As you may know, this is [the official doc](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) about it

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem so many times but this time I found the full proof solution for this issue:

Open **PhpMyAdmin** and then click on **wp_options** table. 
In this, you will see a table with a name(according to your theme name) something like **"theme_options_css"** edit it and change the URL from old to new.

The problem might occur due to **Http to Https** migration also. So for that also change Http to Https manually in the same table and the problem will be resolved the moment you save your table.