# Fonts-Awesome doesn't load fonts when site url is changed from naked to non-naked

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts, font-awesome

For some reason, Font-Awesome stops working the moment I change the site url from from naked to non naked.

Here's the naked link : [http://drnabajborah.com](http://drnabajborah.com/)

I am trying to make it look: [http:www.drnabajborah.com](http://www.drnabajborah.com)

Comment: Neither site loads for me.

Comment: [Please refer to this answer it's working fine Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39077053/font-awesome-icons-not-showing-in-wordpress-after-site-address-url-change)

Answer (score 0):

I haved sorted this out. I changed both the wp url and site url that seem to do the trick. Issue Resolved